# Temporal Analysis using SoilGrids 250m v2.0 - GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, soilgrids

[SoilGrids](https://www.soilgrids.org/) provides the mapping of different properties of soil. I have executed their sample code on Google Earth Engine and it's working fine:

```
var sand_mean = ee.Image('projects/soilgrids-isric/sand_mean')
//print example image metadata and description
print(sand_mean)

//Add all layer to Map
Map.addLayer(sand_mean.select('sand_0-5cm_mean'),{min: 50, max: 1000,palette: ['5d5851','635a4b','6a5b44','715c3d','785e36','7e5f30','856129','8c6222','92641c','996515','a0660e','a66808','ad6901']},'SoilGrids250m 2.0 - Sand content ISRIC_0_5cm')

//Set basemap to Hybrid view
Map.setOptions('HYBRID')
```

But my question is can we do temporal analysis using soilGrids? I can't find **filterDate** property. So, is it possible to see the change in the subsequent years (temporal analysis)?

Comment: No, it is not possible. The ten considered properties (pH in water, texture fractions, coarse fragments, bulk density, total nitrogen, organic carbon concentration and cation exchange capacity) are relatively stable (so, of course, soil moisture is not considered). For instance, clay translocation needs between 500-5000 years (or even more) to be evident. You can read it in this link: https://passel2.unl.edu/view/lesson/293965be23a0/4

Comment: @xunilk What if there is a flood or fire in a certain area? That would change these properties. What will be the mechanism to see the change, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. SoilGrids doesn't provide any date component in the image property through which you can filter for temporal analysis.